# Is it bad practice to use Loaders for network requests?

Tags: android, rest, networking

I have been reading a lot about network operations with android and how to do it properly. The documentation suggests using Volley and it abstracts the process making the network request:

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

As I use Retrofit in my app I thought that the best practice was to use Loaders as they behave well on orientation change, but I found this:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html

"Using a Loader to perform network requests isn't great practice, because (1) it means that your application will be hard on the battery (having to poll for new data from the network repeatedly each time you start the Activity, (2) there is no way to observer the network for content changes without polling it repeatedly, and (3) your application won't work offline."

(1) isn't particularly true because you can just resume the loader on activity creation. I don't think I fully understand point (2) and point (3) isn't a concern for me as there is no way for my app to work properly offline.

However, this caught my eye, again, from the same link.

"So my answer is to forget about using the Loader/AsyncTask combination entirely and to stick with a Service. The Service can poll the network for data every once and a while and insert new data into a ContentProvider. You can then use a CursorLoader to load data from the ContentProvider without it needing to know anything about where the data coming from."

Has anyone used this approach of using a Service to poll the network and populate a ContentProvider? I don't think it will work properly with my app as it uses a RESTful API that is constantly requested. I don't think it will be particular effective, but I might be missing something here.

Sorry for the long question. It is not a question exactly, but I wish to create a discussion around the topic.

Comment: off-topic: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise*